# When I share a HTTPS link to my webpage on Telegram, it doesn't have a preview. How to solve this issue?

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, telegram, facebook-opengraph

I created a webpage which contains Open Graph and Twitter meta-tags. I tested meta tags on different messengers and social networks. Preview of the page is working properly on Facebook, Twitter, Skype, WhatsApp, and Viber, but I have got a problem with Telegram.

If the first time I share a link to my webpage the protocol is HTTPS, then the link is shown without preview. If my link has HTTPS protocol, Telegram ignores Open Graph and Twitter meta-tags and caches an empty preview. I have to use @webpagebot to update preview data. If I use the HTTPS link, @webpagebot ignores preview meta-tags. @webpagebot updates link preview successfully only when I use HTTP (then there are title and description shown).

If I share an HTTP link for the first time, then the link is shown with preview at once.

When I share HTTP/HTTPS links to pages of popular sites (like youtube, etc.) in Telegram, the previews are shown and there is no need in @webpagebot.

I need to make preview working for both  HTTP and HTTPS links without using @webpagebot. The goal is the following: **when a user shares an HTTP/HTTPS link to my website in Telegram, link preview must be displayed at once**.

Could you please tell me the possible reasons for my problem? I suppose that the html code is correct. I tried adding prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" to HTML tag, but it didn't help. 
Maybe I need to change the server configuration? I am using NodeJS with Pug template engine, and Nginx web server.

This is my code on Pug:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en", prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#")
    head
        meta(charset='UTF-8')
        title Test

        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no")

        - var url = 'https://' + req.get('host') + '/test/';

        // Twitter Card meta tags
        meta(name='twitter:url', content=url)
        meta(name='twitter:card', content='summary')
        meta(name='twitter:site', content='@test')
        meta(name='twitter:title', content='Twitter: title')
        meta(name='twitter:description', content='Twitter: description')

        // Open Graph meta tags
        meta(property='og:title', content='Open Graph: title')
        meta(property='og:site_name', content='Test')
        meta(property='og:description', content='Open Graph: description')
        meta(property='og:type', content='website')
        meta(property='og:url', content=url)

        link(rel="canonical", href=url)
    body
        h1 Demo
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Facebook Opengraph Debugger on your webpage?https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Hello. Yes, it works properly, I don't receive any errors.

Comment: The are only 2 warnings I get from Facebook debugger: `(1) The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags` and `(2) The following required properties are missing: og:image, fb:app_id`

Comment: Have you tried using a different internet connection? Sometimes I've found firewall config can stop the preview image loading.